# Content Admin Search Tool Drupal 8

Tags: 8, search

As a content admin, are there any feasible ways in Drupal 8 to search the source HTML of certain Text fields across multiple content types. For example, I want to find all nodes that contain `<div class='special-list'>` in one or more Text fields.

For Drupal 7, it seems that [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) would suffice. Has anyone encountered a similar need in D8?

Answer (score 0):

VBO doesn't search, it only gives you the interface to select items in the Views results and perform actions on them.

To construct the search you want you can use ordinary Views with the `Combine fields filter` filter, here's one video tutorial: [Search across Fields in Views using Combine Fields Filter in Drupal 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xuR2pyhHK4), or use [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) for something more advanced.

Once you have the search working you can add the VBO field if you need to do some actions on the found items.